# Passing components as props?

Tags: vuejs3

I have a component and I pass an icon and a string via a slot:

```
<NavigationItem>
    <TicketIcon class="w-6" />
    <span>Link One</span>
</NavigationItem>
```

I was wondering if this data could be passed via props instead? With the main concern being how would I pass the hero icon `<TicketIcon>` and subsequently other hero icons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Vue3 SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Use `<component>`:

https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-special-elements.html#component

App.vue

```
<script setup>
import Comp from './Comp.vue';
import Container from './Container.vue';
import { ref } from 'vue'

const msg = ref('Hello World!')
</script>

<template>
  <container :component="Comp" :component-props="{text: 'Hello world!'}"></container>
</template>
```

Comp.vue

```
<script setup>
defineProps({text: String});
</script>
<template>{{ text }}</template>
```

Container.vue

```
<script setup>
defineProps({componentProps: Object, component: Object});
</script>
<template>
<component :is="component" v-bind="componentProps"></component>
</template>
```